Как запустить функцию при клике на маркер Yandex Map v3 с использованием кластеризации?
Подскажите пожалуйста.
Ситуация: есть карта с точками. Есть функция showInfo, которая двигает "прицел" карты, меняет Zoom, и информацию по активному поинту в инфо-блок.
Я хочу, чтобы при клике на определенный point запускалась эта функция.
Ума не приложу, куда эту функцию пихать, так как не понимаю (и уже не хочу понимать), как работает yandex map api.
У меня надежда только на доброго человека, потому что я так запарился, что уже мозг отключается
initMap();

async function initMap() {
// Промис ymaps3.ready будет зарезолвлен, когда загрузятся все компоненты основного модуля API
await ymaps3.ready;
const {YMap, YMapDefaultSchemeLayer, YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer, YMapMarker, YMapControls, YMapLayer, YMapFeatureDataSource} = ymaps3;

const {YMapZoomControl} = await ymaps3.import('@yandex/ymaps3-controls@0.0.1');

// Добавляем кластеризатор
const {YMapClusterer, clusterByGrid} = await ymaps3.import('@yandex/ymaps3-clusterer@0.0.1');

// Иницилизируем карту
const map = new YMap(
    // Передаём ссылку на HTMLElement контейнера
    document.getElementById('map'),

    // Передаём параметры инициализации карты
    {
        location: {
            // Координаты центра карты
            center: [37.588144, 55.733842],

            // Уровень масштабирования
            zoom: 10
        }
    }
);

// Добавляем слой для отображения схематической карты
map.addChild(new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer({ customization: mapCustomizationJSON }));

// Добавляем к карте ресурс
map.addChild(new YMapFeatureDataSource({id:'my-source'}));
// Добавляем ресурс на карту
map.addChild(new YMapLayer({source: 'my-source', type: 'markers', zIndex:1800}));

// Пин
const contentPin = document.createElement('div');
contentPin.innerHTML = '<img style="width:20px;" src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/pin-png/pin-transparent-png-pictures-icons-and-png-backgrounds-36.png" />';

// Функция создания маркера (или че это)
function marker(feature) {
    const yMapMarker = new ymaps3.YMapMarker(
        {
            coordinates: feature.geometry.coordinates,
            source: 'my-source'
        },
        contentPin.cloneNode(true)
    );

    // yMapMarker.events.add('click', () => {
    //     showInfo(feature);
    // });

    return yMapMarker;
}

const cluster = (coordinates, features) =>
new ymaps3.YMapMarker(
    {
        coordinates,
        source: 'my-source'
    },
    circle(features.length).cloneNode(true)
);

function circle(count) {
    const circle = document.createElement('div');
    circle.classList.add('circle');
    circle.innerHTML = `
    <div class="circle-content"><span class="circle-text">${count}</span></div>`;
    return circle;
}

const points = pointsData.map((point, i) => ({
    type: 'Feature',
    id: i,
    geometry: {coordinates: [point.acf_fields.coordinates.y, point.acf_fields.coordinates.x]},
    properties: {
        name: point.acf_fields.point_name,
        // другие свойства
    }
}))

const clusterer = new YMapClusterer({
    method: clusterByGrid({gridSize: 64}),
    features: points,
    marker,
    cluster
});

map.addChild(clusterer);

//   Пытаюсь добавить кнопку Зума
map.addChild(
    // Using YMapControls you can change the position of the control
    new YMapControls({position: 'right'})
    // Add the zoom control to the map
    .addChild(new YMapZoomControl({}))
);

map.addChild(new YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer());

// Функция отображения информации
function showInfo(feature) {
    const infoElement = document.getElementById('point-info-container');
    
    // Вставляем в элемент inf-block данные, которые мы получим из переменной point
    document.getElementById('point-info__name').innerText = 'Info';
    document.getElementById('point-info__address').innerText = 'text';
    infoElement.style.display = 'block';

    map.update({
        location: {
            center: feature.geometry.coordinates,
            zoom: 14,
            duration: 1000,
        }
    });
    
}

P.s
Я так понял, это можно сделать через marker(feature). Я пытался это сделать так
function marker(feature) {
        const yMapMarker = new ymaps3.YMapMarker(
            {
                coordinates: feature.geometry.coordinates,
                source: 'my-source'
            },
            contentPin.cloneNode(true)
        );

        yMapMarker.events.add('click', () => {
            showInfo(feature);
        });

        return yMapMarker;
    }

Но получил ошибку.
test:55 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
    at Object.marker (test:55:27)
    at c._getEntity (clusterer.js:1:1093)
    at clusterer.js:1:1228
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c._getVisibleEntities (clusterer.js:1:1202)
    at c._render (clusterer.js:1:1916)
    at c._onAttach (clusterer.js:1:2319)
    at c.AEC__implAttach (main.js:1:58810)
    at c.C57__implAttachTo (main.js:1:58391)
    at d._addDirectChild (main.js:1:61583)


Благодарю ребят из Яндекс.
Получил ответ непосредственно от них. Спасибо, Виктор А.

Нужно использовать onClick. Он работает и на YMapMarker, и на YMapFeature.

Как выглядит моё решение:
function marker(feature) {
    const yMapMarker = new ymaps3.YMapMarker(
        {
            coordinates: feature.geometry.coordinates,
            source: 'my-source',
            onClick() {
                 // Всё что вам нужно
                 // В моём случае это showInfo, в которую я предаю свой объект
                 showInfo(feature);
            }
        },
        contentPin.cloneNode(true)
    );

    return yMapMarker;
}

